Issue while writing Unit Test case with jest for testing a function depends on AuthContext state
I am getting an issue "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_context')Jest" while writing Unit Test Case with jest in my react native project with java script.
I have follow below approach, Please review and let me know what I am doing wrong.
TestCase
test.only('Fill little about you form with correct details (student) and navigate to Create Password', async () => {
  render(
    <MockAuthContextProvider value={{postUserDetails}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="LittleAboutYou"
            component={LittleAboutYou}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Create Password"
            component={CreatePassword}
            options={{ headerShown: true }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </MockAuthContextProvider>
  );

 await waitFor(() => {
    const view = screen.getByTestId('little-about-you-view');
    expect(view).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});


I have mocked AuthContext, implementation is below:
import React from 'react'

const MockAuthContext = React.createContext()

export const mockAuthContextValue = {
  automaticLogin: jest.fn(),
  logout: jest.fn(),
  setAppleSignInData: jest.fn(),
  setGoogleSignInData: jest.fn(),
  // setRole: jest.fn(),
  postUserDetails: jest.fn(),
  postDemographics: jest.fn(),
  loading: false,
  role: 'student',
  loginWithGoogle: jest.fn(),
  googleSignInData: null,
  loginWithApple: jest.fn(),
  appleSignInData: null,
  postUserDetailsExceptEmail: jest.fn(),
  postFacultyDetails: jest.fn(),
  setFacultySelectedInstitute: jest.fn(),
  registrationID: '12345',
}

export const MockAuthContextProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
  return <MockAuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</MockAuthContext.Provider>
}
export const MockAuthConsumer = (Child) => (props) =>
  (
    <MockAuthContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => <Child {...props} {...context} />}
    </MockAuthContext.Consumer>
  )


LittleAboutYou is a UI Component for which I want to write test case, it has API calls
I have already mocked "axios"
function LittleAboutYou({ navigation }) {
  const {
    postUserDetails,
    loading,
    role,
    loginWithGoogle,
    googleSignInData,
    loginWithApple,
    appleSignInData,
    postUserDetailsExceptEmail,
    postFacultyDetails,
    setFacultySelectedInstitute,
    registrationID,
  } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log("handleSubmit", role);
    logToCloudWatch({ logMessage: `Submit button pressed` })
    analytics().logEvent('letUsKnowAboutYou_submit_clicked', {
      ...values,
      institution,
      fields: field,
    })
    if (validate(values, role) !== '') {
      showToast(validate(values, role))
      return
    }
     //Status is 201 is already checked in Auth context
    if (role === 'student') {
      const res = await postUserDetails(values)
      console.log("handleSubmit response", res);
      //Status is 201 is already checked in Auth context

      res && navigation.navigate(role === 'student' ? 'Create Password' : 'Create Password', {
        email: values.email,
        type: '',
      })
    } else if (role === 'faculty') {
      const urlExpression =
        /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi

      const urlRegex = new RegExp(urlExpression)

      if (institution === '') {
        showToast('Institution cannot be empty')
        return
      }
      if (!!values.googleScholarLink && !values.googleScholarLink.match(urlRegex)) {
        showToast('Please enter a valid google scholar url')
        return
      }

      if (field === '') {
        showToast('Field cannot be empty')
        return
      }

      const payload = {
        ...values,
        institution,
        fields: field,
      }

      setFacultySelectedInstitute(institution)

      const response = await postFacultyDetails(payload)
      response && navigation.navigate('Faculty: Select Profile', { userDetails: payload })
    }
  }
}

for more details please let me know.
Thanks in advance.
I have provided implementation, please review.

I am also facing same issue.
